# Show $\sum\limits_{d|n}\phi(d) = n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, totient-function

Show $\sum\limits_{d|n}\phi(d) = n$.

Example : $\sum\limits_{d|4}\phi(d) = \phi(1) + \phi(2) + \phi(4) = 1 + 1 + 2 = 4$

I was told this has a simple proof. Problem is, I can not think of a way to show this in a very simple and straightforward way.

Comment: Show it for prime powers (elementary), and then show that the sum is a multiplicative function, that means for $m,n$ coprime, you have $$\sum_{d\mid mn} \phi(d) = \left(\sum_{e \mid m} \phi(e)\right)\left(\sum_{g\mid n}\phi(g)\right).$$

Comment: Alternatively consider the set of cyclic subgroups of the multiplicative group and their corresponding orders.

Comment: Since this came from an abstract algebra course your idea Alex is probably the right direction to head in. Would you be able to provide an example of what your talking about Alex?

Answer (score 20):

Let $G=\langle x\rangle$ be the cyclic group of order $n$ generated by $x$. Then,
\begin{align}
n &= |G| \\
&= \sum_{1\leq d\leq n} |\{\text{elements of order } d\}| \\
&= \sum_{d|n}|\{\text{elements of order } d\}|
\end{align}
by Lagrange's Theorem. But $G$ has a unique cyclic subgroup of order $d$ for each $d|n$, namely $\langle x^{n/d}\rangle$. Moreover, each such subgroup has $\varphi(d)$ generators, so
$$n = \sum_{d|n}\varphi(d)$$

Comment: best proof I've seen for this by far +2

Answer (score 16):

Hint: You can show that $\sum\limits_{d|n}\phi(d) = \sum\limits_{d|n}\phi(\frac{n}{d}) $ but $\phi(\frac{n}{d})$ is all numbers with GCD of $d$ with $n$. Therefore the last sum counts all numbers till $n$ and is equal to $n$.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest proof I know is this:

Consider all proper fractions of the form $a/n$. There are $n$ of those. When you consider their reduced forms you get fractions of the form $b/d$ with $d|n$ and $(b,d)=1$. By definition, there are $\phi(d)$ of those. The result follows.

Comment: For a given $d_1$, how is it guaranteed that *all* $b$ such that $(b,d_1)=1$ will appear as the numerators in the reduced set of fractions? This is the point that's hindering me from believing the next part of the argument "there are $\phi(d_1)$ of those".

Answer (score 7):

Here's one approach:

Consider the polynomial $x^n-1$ as a polynomial over the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. You can easily see, almost tautologically, that

$$x^n-1=\prod_{d\mid n}\Phi_d(x)\qquad(\ast)$$

where $\Phi_d(x)$ is the polynomial whose roots are the primitive $d^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity (i.e. solutions to $x^d-1$ that do not satisfy $x^c-1$ for $0<c<d$).

But, rephrasing the definition, $\Phi_d(x)$ is the polynomial with roots $e^{\frac{2\pi i r}{d}}$ where $e^{\frac{2\pi r s}{d}}\ne 1$ for $0<s<d$. But, this is saying that $sr\not\equiv 0\mod d$ for $0<s<d$, or that $d$ and $r$ have no common factors. Since we only need to care about $r$ which are less than or equal to $d$ we see that, in fact, the are $\phi(d)$ such roots of $\Phi_d(x)$.

This allows us to conclude that $\deg \Phi_d(x)=\phi(d)$. Indeed, since $\Phi_d(x)\mid x^n-1$, and $x^n-1$ has no repeated roots in $\mathbb{C}$ (it's coprime to its derivative) we see that $\Phi_d(x)$ has no repeated roots. Thus, $\deg\Phi_d(x)$ is the number of roots of $\Phi_d(x)$ which is $\phi(d)$.

So, by comparing degrees in $(\ast)$ we get:

$$n=\sum_{d\mid n}\deg\Phi_d(x)=\sum_{d\mid n}\phi(d)$$

Comment: This is a very nice method.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the set $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ of size $n$. Define an equivalence relation as follows $$m\sim m'\iff (m,n)=(m',n)$$ That this is an equivalence relation should be clear. The equivalence classes are of the form $$\widehat m=\{0<m'\leqslant n:(m',n)=d\}$$ where $d=(m,n)\mid n$.  Now, what is the size of this class? It contains all positive elements $m'\leqslant n$ such that $(m',n)=d$, or what is the same, all positive elements $$\frac{m'}d\leqslant \frac nd$$ such that $$\left(\frac{m'}{d},\frac nd \right)=1$$

This amounts to $\varphi\left(\dfrac nd\right)$ elements. But there is one class for each positive divisor of $n$, thus we have paititioned our set getting $$n=\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi\left(\dfrac nd\right)$$

But as $d$ runs through all divisors of $n$; so does $\dfrac nd$, so that $$n=\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d)$$