# Multiple proofs of $\sum_{d|n}{\phi(d)}=n$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, alternative-proof, big-list

I am looking for multiple proofs of that statement: here $\phi(n)$ denotes the Euler’s totient 
$$\sum_{d|n}{\phi(d)}=n$$

Here’s one:

By unique factorisation theorem:
$n=\prod_{k=1}^{m}{p_k^{\alpha_k}}$ and $d=\prod_{k=1}^{m}{p_k^{\beta_k}}$ where $0\leq \beta_k\leq \alpha_k$ so:

\begin{align}
\sum_{d|n}{\phi(d)}&=\sum_{0\leq \beta_k\leq \alpha_k}{\phi\left(\prod_{k=1}^{m}{p_k^{\beta_k}}\right)}\\
&= \sum_{0\leq \beta_k\leq \alpha_k}{\prod_{k=1}^{m}\phi({p_k^{\beta_k})}}\\
&=\sum_{0\leq \beta_k\leq \alpha_k}{\prod_{k=1}^{m}{(p_k^{\beta_k}-p_k^{\beta_k-1}})}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{m}{\sum_{0\leq \beta_k\leq \alpha_k}{(p_k^{\beta_k}-p_k^{\beta_k-1}}})\\
&= \prod_{k=1}^{m}{p_k^{\alpha_k}}\\
&=n.
\end{align}

Comment: Titles that are only MathJax are not particularly useful for searching by future people looking for an answer to the same question.

Comment: if you have a number theory "multiplicative" function $f,$ then $g(n) = \sum_{d|n} f(d)$ is also multiplicative. The values of a multipicative function are determined by its values for primes and prime powers.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048209/easiest-proof-for-sum-dn-phid-n/1048215 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194705/is-there-a-direct-elementary-proof-of-n-sum-kn-phik/194713#194713

Answer (score 2):

Other proof: let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $n$; then it has exactly $\phi(d)$ elements of order $d$ for each $d$ that divides $n$, and by Lagrange theorem, the order of each element has to divide the order of the group: but the group has $n$ elements. So you got exactly that $\sum_{d|n} \phi(d)=n$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $φ$ is a multiplicative function, therefore its dirichlet convolution is multiplicative too. Since $N(n)=n$ is also a multiplicative function, it suffices to show that $N$ and $(φ*1)$ agree on all prime powers.

Now check that $\sum_{d|p^r} φ(p^r)=φ(1)+φ(p)+...+φ(p^r)=(p-1)+p(p-1)+p^2(p-1)+...+p^{r-1}(p-1)=(p-1)(1+p+p^2+...+p^{r-1})=(p-1)\frac{p^r-1}{p-1}=p^r$