# Is $\phi (k_1) + \phi (k_2)+\phi (k_3) +...\phi (k_n)=gcd(m, n) $ ? k is divisor of m and n

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function, gcd-and-lcm

> Let $k_1, k_2, k_3,\dots ,k_n$ be positive divisors of $m$ and $n$. Can you prove or disprove the following $$\varphi (k_1) + \varphi (k_2)+\varphi (k_3) +\dots+\varphi (k_n)=\gcd(m, n).$$

Comment: Does $k_1, k_2, k_3,... k_n$ involve all the positive divisors of m and n??

Comment: In general $\sum_{d|n}\varphi(d)=n$.  See, eg, [this](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Euler%27s_totient_function)

Comment: @schrodinger. Yes,

Comment: @lulu.oh,thanks for the idea, it give a lot for my friends

Comment: @lulu An MSE-link is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504063/show-sum-limits-dn-phid-n). Hence $\sum_{d\mid (n,m)}\phi(d)=(n,m)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Thanks!  I searched for such (but obviously not hard enough).

Comment: @dietrich, oh the formula is the key! Thank you, its very useful for my firends presentation.